# Mover elemento especifico a la derecha usando flex

Tags: css

Resulta que tengo una grilla de thumbs y estoy usando por primera vez **flexbox** por su sencillez y menor uso de líneas en el código.

Quiero ubicar siempre arriba a la derecha un banner de publicidad, el problema está en que se carga en la tercera ubicación de la primera fila, pero en pantallas grandes donde tienen más de tres columnas por fila no sé como ubicarla al estilo `float: right;`. No quiero usar javascript porque demora unos mili segundos en actuar, y el cambio es evidente.

Aquí les dejo una ilustración por si no me expliqué bien:
[image]
Este es el código por el momento:

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
  width: calc(20% - 15px);
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #9e9f9a;
  margin: 0 15px 20px 0;
}
ul li.ad {
  background-color: #ff00d8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="ad"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Si entiendo bien los elementos van cayendo o subiendo dependiendo del ancho de la ventana y lo que se busca es que el ad siempre esté a la derecha?

Comment: Exacto @KacosPro, la idea es que siempre se ubique arriba a la derecha. En el ejemplo me falto agregar mas filas.

Comment: Y siempre está en esa posición? No es posible cambiarlo a la primera?

Comment: Siempre, no puedo cambiarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres declarando el `order: -1;` al elemento que siempre quieres que esté arriba y asignarle `flex-direction: row-reverse;` al contenedor

Pruebalo a pantalla completa y cambia el ancho de esta :)

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

ul {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #9e9f9a;
  margin: 0 15px 20px 0;
}

ul li.ad {
  order: -1;
  background-color: #ff00d8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="ad"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Ahora si aparte quieres que los elementos caigan al inicio de la siguiente fila puedes declarar `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

ul {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #9e9f9a;
  margin: 0 15px 20px 0;
}

ul li.ad {
  order: -1;
  background-color: #ff00d8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="ad"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no se aplicaría en mi caso porque debe darse el corte de 3/4/5 thumbs por fila.

Comment: @tomillo edité mi respuesta, debería satisfacer los requerimientos ahora

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @KacosPro!

Comment: De nada @tomillo :D

Answer (score 2):

Prueba usando **`order`**.

> Por defecto, los elementos flexibles se presentan en el orden de
>   origen. Sin embargo, la orderpropiedad controla el orden en que
>   aparecen en el contenedor flexible.

Si vamos dando valor a la propiedad `order` podemos establecer el orden de los elementos, por ejemplo, tenemos 3 `div`'s, pues ponemos `order:1`, `order:3` y `order:2` a cada uno, y se van a posicionar de la manera que hemos especificado.

Te dejo la [documentación](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
  width: calc(20% - 15px);
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #9e9f9a;
  margin: 0 15px 20px 0;
}
ul li.ad {
  background-color: #ff00d8;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="ad"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Impresionante la velocidad de la respuesta. Muchas gracias. Pero me ha faltado un detalle, no solo es una fila de 5 divs, sinó es una grilla de mínimo 20 divs. Lo he probado con `order: 5` pero se ubica debajo de toda la grilla.

Comment: Tienes que ir jugando junto con los demas elementos, la página que he compartido lo explica muy bien.

Comment: Debes hacer un div display:flex para cada fila del grid y alli darle el order al elemento que quieres que vaya al final

Comment: Lo pude corroborar y funciona bien. De todas maneras no puedo resolver el problema del responsive, porque debería si estoy en una pantalla de 1600px el **ad** se ubica `order: 5;`, pero cambio a 1400px el **ad** debería tener `order: 4;`. La única manera de hacer eso es usando Javascript y me gustaría evitarlo.

Comment: Este ya es otro asunto, puedes resolverlo con jquery... pero debes formular una nueva pregunta, tu actual pregunta ya esta resuelta